# Stuck reinstalling OSX Catalina

Tags: macos-catalina

I wanted to wipe and reinstall my 2018 MacBook Air with a T2 security chip.  I am running into a problem with an intermittent internet connection.

I erased the Hard Drive in recovery mode with Disk Utility, and then went to Reinstall macOS from the macOS Utilities window in recovery mode.  My internet connection drops out intermittently and it fails.  I created bootable installation media from my other laptop, but I can't use it because of the settings in [Startup Security Utility](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198).  I can't get into Startup Security Utility because there is no administrator account on the computer to authenticate with after erasing it.

I'm at a loss.  Intermittent internet connectivity is just a reality where I live.  I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Shut down your Mac and restart it by pressing **Option+Command+R**. Then erase the startup disk and reinstall macOS.

Hope it will work for you.